# drupal_set_title not changing the navigation bar title

Tags: 7

I have changed the title of a path with the drupal_set_title() function from hook_page_alter from a custom module. It works but the title in the navigation bar is still the previous one.

How can I change it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're setting the title too late in the theme building process for this to work, possibly using at the node layer which only affects the node title not the page title. What you want to make sure to do is use a preprocess_page function to set the title so this is in the header as well:

[image: from page_title module on drupal.org]

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars){
    if (isset($vars['node'])) {
        drupal_set_title('YOUR TITLE');
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can install the [Page Title](https://drupal.org/project/page_title) which gives you granular control over all of your page titles and is often recommended for SEO.

Comment: The code returns me the same result. The 'Page Title' module solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: The first half of this answer is wrong. It needs to be set even earlier. But what would be an appropriate hook?